# Побитовый сдвиг

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Пишу скрипт на php. Есть числа:
16359391
15382371
7177275
15318085
16431130

Пример чисел из программы, с каждым числом происходит >> 8 и получается число меньше, а когда делать побитовый сдвиг с результатом только << 8, значение с начальным не сходится. Скажите, как делать побитовый сдвиг без потери чисел и чтобы при сдвиге в одну из сторон число было длинной на 2 цифри меньше? или может есть какой-нибудь другой вариант? Самое главное в задаче это уменьшить данное число на 2 цифри и чтобы его можно обратно перевести в начальное число.
Должно получается примерно так для разных чисел:
16359391
63903
16359391

**UPD:**

Вот пример кода: Есть таблица

```
$table = array(
    0x003b6c1c, 
    0x002def61, 
    0x006effa2, 
    0x0013045f, 
    0x00873358, 
    0x0039e1fd, 
    0x0061491a, 
    0x002608bf, 
    0x00254ed0, 
    0x004fc7dd, 
    0x00721a32, 
    0x0018dce3, 
    0x001328bc, 
    0x003e288d, 
    0x0084387e, 
    0x004c11e3);
$table_index = 13; 
$b = 16359391; 
$result = $b ^ $table[$table_index]; 
$resultfinal = ($result >> 8).$table_index;
```

И нужно с $resultfinal получить 16359391, учитывая что начальное значение и индекс в таблице неизвестно, известно только последнее значение.

Comment: как вы себе представляете это? Если вы уменьшили длину числа, то как вернуть обратно потерянные цифры?

Comment: чем вас  не устраивает разделить на 100, и при необходимости выводить целую часть? Лучше опишите суть задачи, зачем вам это вообще надо?

Comment: сдвиг без потерь - циклический сдвиг. Арифметический и циклический - понятия разные,  числа выйдут соовсем другие.

Comment: Поправил ваш вопрос. Я так понял, что `$table_index` и `$b` вам не известны, а известен только `$result` из которого надо выудить начальное число? Там же у вас $result через XOR вычисляется, да?

Comment: чуток ошибка в коде    
  вместо $resultfinal = ($b >> 8).$table_index;    
  нужно  $resultfinal = ($result >> 8).$table_index;    
  а так верно, да, просто в переменную $resultfinal записывается $result >> 8 и добавляется 2 цифри(индекс значения в таблце)

Comment: вот всё думаю, как выполнить задачу

Comment: rjhdby, поможете?

Answer (score 1):

Как работает побитовый сдвиг.

Рассмотрим совсем простой случай, для одного беззнакового байта и без переполнений.

Допустим есть у нас 1 байт равный `FF`. В двоичном представлении это будет `11111111`

Сдвинем его вправо `11111111 >> 1 = 0111111`. Крайняя правая единица при этом теряется. Насовсем. Как небыло. Сдвинем теперь получившееся число обратно, влево `01111111 << 1 = 11111110`

Если первой операцией сдвигать влево, то совершенно по тому же принципу потеряется начальный бит.

Теперь про ваш случай. Так как PHP оперирует динамическим приведением типов, то можно(в разумных пределах) воспользоваться знанием о том, что побитовый сдвиг влево равнозначен умножению на 2 (на бесконечном количестве бит), а сдвиг вправо - равнозначен делению на два.

Т.е. для решения вашей задачи нужно использовать не сдвиг, а математические операции умножения и деления.

```
$a = 16359391;
$a_shifted = $a / (2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2); // аналогично $a >> 8
$a_unshifted = $a_shifted * (2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2); // аналогично $a_shifted << 8
```

Но тут надо понимать, что при этом у вас может произойти преобразование int в float с возможной потерей точности

Comment: всё-таки может есть какие-нибудь варианты для выполнения данной задачи? может попробывать число перевести в двоичную систему счисления и с помощью какого-то алгоритма сжать двоичное число, а потом перевести в десятеричную и на выходе получится целое число но меньше. Не знаете про такие алгоритмы?

Comment: @Aleks у меня есть подозрение, что вы пытаетесь закручивать гвозди отверткой вместо использования молотка. Конечная то цель какая? зачем вам именно сдвиг?

Comment: мне нужен не обязательно сдвиг, любые операции с числом, главное чтобы с него можно было получать число на 2 цифри меньше и без потерь обратно получить начальное значение с этого числа

Comment: @Aleks при такой постановке задачи, как вы ее описываете, она решения не имеет. Попробуйте все же описать более глобальную цель. Например для чего вам число на две цифры меньше? На экран выводить? Хранить в БД? еще для чего?

Comment: Вот пример кода:

Есть таблица $table = array(0x003b6c1c, 0x002def61, 0x006effa2, 0x0013045f, 0x00873358, 0x0039e1fd, 0x0061491a, 0x002608bf, 0x00254ed0, 0x004fc7dd, 0x00721a32, 0x0018dce3, 0x001328bc, 0x003e288d, 0x0084387e, 0x004c11e3);

$table_index = 13;

$b = 16359391;


$result = $b ^ $table[$table_index];

$resultfinal = ($b >> 8).$table_index;

И нужно с $resultfinal получить 16359391, учитывая что начальное значение и индекс в таблице неизвестно, известно только последнее значение.